# Transform api result to collect additional data from additional api requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an api call that returns a list of results as an `Observable<any[]>`.  Ultimately, I want to show these data in a list but the list should contain other data for each record that doesn't come along with that first request.

I think this is a pretty simple plain description of the problem:  Give an observable of an array, I would like to transform each item in the array by calling a web service and then return a modified observable of an array.

```
getActivePosts = (): Observable<Post[]> => {
  return this.get('/Post/Active')
    .pipe(
      map(posts => posts.map(u => ({
        title: u.title,
        author: u.author,
        rating: 0      // <- This is the value I have to look up elsewhere
       })))
    );
}
```

So the above would give me the array of posts, but with all `rating` values would be `0`.

My thinking is that I need to turn the array into a stream so I can operate on each element.  Then I could use `toArray` to put the items back into an array afterwards.  This would look like the following, I would assume:

```
getActivePosts = (): Observable<Post[]> => {
  return this.get('/Post/Active')
    .pipe(
      map(posts => posts.map(u => ({
        title: u.title,
        author: u.author,
        rating: 0      // <- This is the value I have to look up elsewhere
       }))),
    switchMap(posts => from(posts)),
    tap(post => console.log('Do something with this individual item...', post)),
    toArray()
    );
}
```

Even before I figure out the (perhaps) trickier part of calling the next api to get the ratings (currently just the `tap` to show a console message), I'm already stuck.  This example never gets past `toArray` because the inner stream (created by `from`) never completes.  When this code runs and a subscription is made to the result of this function (outer observable?) nothing is emitted.  I can confirm that the initial api call is made and devtools shows that the response is an array, as expected.

How do I do something on each item in the array and still return an array?  I would love to solve this "The rxjs way" if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your use cases is pretty common now a days. You can use following code -

```
getActivePosts = (): Observable<Post[]> => {
  return this.get('/Post/Active')
    .pipe(
      map(posts => posts.map(u => ({
        title: u.title,
        author: u.author,
        rating: 0      // <- This is the value I have to look up elsewhere
       }))),
      mergeMap(post => this.getRating(post[id]) //check the id
               .pipe(
                  tap(rating => post.rating = rating;
               )
       ),
    toArray()
    );
}
```